When is an object no longer considered orbiting a celestial body during its descent?
During the Apollo mission, once the LM began its descent to the surface of the moon, was it still in orbit about the moon?

This sounds like a vocabulary question more than physics. An unpowered body is in orbit around the moon if its trajectory goes around the moon. If it is braking with a rocket, I am not sure I would call it an orbit. If it shuts off the engine and the new trajectory carries it into the moon, you might call it an orbit around the center of mass of the moon.

In spaceflight terms, if the trajectory intersects the body (and is outside the atmosphere), it is known as a suborbital trajectory. As far as the physics is concerned, though, it is still in an elliptical orbit.
